# How to increase a cell array size?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell, dimensions

I have a cell array with the dimensions of: 1x11x2

I want to increase it to 3x11x2 by adding a row of ' '

How do I do that?

For ex.: Array A:

```
a(:,:,1) = 

    'Value3'    ''    ''    'Value1'    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''


a(:,:,2) = 

    ''    ''    ''    ''    'Error'    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''
```

And I want it to be:

```
a(:,:,1) = 

    'Value3'    ''    ''    'Value1'    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''
    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''

a(:,:,2) = 

    ''    ''    ''    ''    'Error'    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''
    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''    ''
```

Comment: Note that is not a matrix, it's a cell array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most generic code would be:

```
a = [a; reshape(repmat({''},1,size(a,2)*size(a,3)),1,size(a,2),size(a,3))];
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This triggers an error `??? Error using ==> vertcat, CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.`

Comment: Ooops my bad, checked it only with 1x2 matrix, should be fine now... Thanks for the checkup

Comment: This is not so generic. For example, you should be using `size(a, 3)`. I fixed your code.

Comment: No problem. +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm pretty new in the Matlab thing and it is still very confusing to me.
So to better understand your solution - What should be the code if I want to increase the A matrix from 3x11x2 to 3x11x3? (now increase the Zaxis)

Comment: Also - using repeat function as such is the same as what you wrote, right?:

repmat({''},[1 size(a,2) size(a,3)])

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer, but this should allow you to easily get the right amount of empty strings:

```
regexprep(a(:,:,1),'.','')
```

Comment: If a(:, :, i) contains more than one row, you'll create multiple empty rows instead of only one.